# What is the OpenXML SDK alternative to InsertFile?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm currently working on a project that requires me to be able to merge two word documents.  Right now I'm using automation and having Word merge them via `InsertFile`.  It has come to my attention though that automating Word on the server is bad practice.  So how would I go about this using OpenXML SDK or something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a nice wrapper API (**Document Builder 2.2**) around open xml specially designed to merge documents, with flexibility of choosing the paragraphs to merge etc. You can download it from [here](http://powertools.codeplex.com/releases/view/74771).

The documentation and screen casts on how to use it are [here](http://openxmldeveloper.org/wiki/w/wiki/documentbuilder.aspx).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AltChunk as explained @
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/10/27/how-to-use-altchunk-for-document-assembly.aspx